# Can an operator $T$ in a countable infinite-dimension vector space have uncountable many eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In the finite-dimensional case there can not be more eigenvalues than the dimension of the space, but this example seems to show that it does not hold in the infinite-dimensional case. 
Let $T$ be the operator over the space of real sequences that makes a backward shift, i.e. $$T(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)=(x_2,x_3,\ldots)$$
Then any real number $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue associated to the eigenspace consisting of all sequences of the form $$x_n=\lambda^{n-1}x$$ where $x$ ranges over $\mathbb{R}$.

So we have uncontable many eigenvalues for an operator on a countable infinite-dimension space. How can I interpret this result? It feels counterintuitive to me.

Comment: The vector space of real sequences $(x_n)_n$ has not countable dimension! Indeed, if you take as a basis the usual $e_i=(0, \dots , 0, 1, 0 , \dots )$, where the $i$th component is the unique $1$, you can span only finitely many nonzero components. For example, $(1,2,2^2, 2^3, 2^4, \dots)$ cannot be spanned by finitely many elements of the standard basis.

Comment: @Crostul why, isn't the standard base countable?

Comment: @Eliana: A basis is a linearly independent set $S$ such that every element in the vector space can be expressed as a *finite* linear combination of elements of $S$. There is no such thing as an infinite linear combination.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan yes, I see my mistake, thanks. But coming back to the question of the title, so is it a general result that there can not be more eigenvalues than the dimension of the space?

Comment: A Hamel basis is one in which any point is contained in the linear span of a finite number of elements of the basis. A Schauder basis is a countable collection of elements in which any point is contained in the closure of the linear span of the elements.